# react router nested routing approach

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React router 4 official docs have such example for nested route

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    {/* here's a div */}
    <div>
      {/* here's a Route */}
      <Route path="/tacos" component={Tacos}/>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)

// when the url matches `/tacos` this component renders
const Tacos  = ({ match }) => (
  // here's a nested div
  <div>
    {/* here's a nested Route,
        match.url helps us make a relative path */}
    <Route
      path={match.url + '/carnitas'}
      component={Carnitas}
    />
  </div>
)
```

My question is I think I could have achieved same effect using such setup
(instead of putting `Carnitas` inside `Tacos` component, to write it out directly
next to `Tacos`)

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    {/* here's a div */}
    <div>
      {/* here's a Route */}
      <Route path="/tacos" component={Tacos}/>
      <Route
      path={'tacos/carnitas'}
      component={Carnitas}
    />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)

// when the url matches `/tacos` this component renders
const Tacos  = ({ match }) => (
  // here's a nested div
  <div>

  </div>
)
```

What is the limitation of second approach as compared to first one?

Comment: You don't have to put all your routes in one file is the advantage here.